# Reach Html control from Code-behind

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I would like to know how I can reach attributes in code behind (if possible) added to the HTML control using jQuery!

I have this ASP.NET-control:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="myID" CssClass="class1 class2 " runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

In jQuery I set it to:

```
var myInput = $(control).find('#<%= myID.ClientID %>');
myInput.addClass('class3');
```

My problem is that I am not able to see in code behind that I have added `class3`?

Comment: You should be able to see the TextBox's CssClass property in code behind (at least in debug mode) but it depends on when you call your JQuery and when you are checking the CssClass property from code behind.

Comment: @Sam In debug mode I am only able to see "class1 class2" on the CssClass. I guess the addClass only sets the class to the DOM and not to the server-objekt.

Comment: I gues I'm wrong. Priyank and Peter are correct with their answers. Sorry! Good question. Learned something today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A page only post name value pairs of the form element to the server. So the code behind on the postback has only viewstate and new name value collection of form elements. So there is no straight way that a code behind may now what modification you have done using jquery in the dom except the values in the form element. And if the class is added at compile time or in code behind, this information is maintained in view state and page with the help of view state restores the control properties.  If it is really needed in your current task then you can put name of the class in any hidden element using jquery and get the values of the hidden element in code behind.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. You use client code to add class, buy during the post operation only the form values posted, not the entire html. Check it with fiddle for example. That is not how http work.

Answer (score 0):

```
myID.Attributes["class"]
```

haven't actually tried to do this, but that's what I'd try.

Comment: Yeah, was a bit of a stretch :P